# How to escape "and" as list delimiter in bibtex/biblatex?

Tags: biblatex, parsing

In my BibLaTeX manual, it says:

> Literal lists are parsed and split up into the individual items at the `and` delimiter
>   but not dissected further. Literal lists may be truncated in the bib file with
>   the keyword ‘and others’. There are two subtypes:
>
> Literal lists in the strict sense are handled as described above. The individual
>   items are simply printed as is. Typical examples of such literal lists are
>   publisher and location.

So, let's say I want to record associated institutions in a list field - I'd be supposed to use "and" as delimiter. But how do you handle an institution having "and" in the name (e.g. "Foundation of Science of São Tomé and Príncipe")? Then I'd have to write, e.g

```
publisher = { Foundation of Science of São Tomé and Príncipe and Johnson and Johnson Fund for Scientific Research },
```

... and I can already now tell that the parser will break, and give me a wrong list of institutions for that field written as is.

So, how does one approach this? Would double quotes hint to the parser not to use "and" inside quotes as a list delimiter:

```
publisher = { "Foundation of Science of São Tomé and Príncipe" and "Johnson and Johnson Fund for Scientific Research" },
```

... or, I've seen `\and` as command in Biblatex - maybe that can be used to hint to the parser, to ignore the other, non-command "and"s as list delimiters (or the opposite - not to consider command `\and`s as delimiters)?:

```
publisher = { Foundation of Science of São Tomé and Príncipe \and Johnson and Johnson Fund for Scientific Research },
```

I'm primarily interested in using BibLaTeX with fields like these — but if there's a generic approach that handles BibTeX too, I'd love to know that.

Comment: Have you tried `publisher = {{Foundation of Science of São Tomé and Príncipe} and {Johnson and Johnson Fund for Scientific Research}}`?

Comment: Many thanks @PhelypeOleinik - haven't tried that, but that looks like it will work! Forgot how groupings go with braces in Latex ... Thanks again!

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik Do you want to type that up as an answer that can be accepted. If you'd like to back it up with quotes from the `biblatex` docs, §2.3.4 *Literal Lists* pp. 34-35 (v3.14) is the section to look at.

Answer (score 4):

Both Biber and BibTeX will only see the keyword `and` if it is not inside any braces, so you can type the `publisher` field (or any other field that uses `and` as separator) like this:

```
publisher = {{Foundation of Science of São Tomé and Príncipe}
             and
             {Johnson and Johnson Fund for Scientific Research}}
```

or even just hide the literal `and` inside braces:

```
publisher = {Foundation of Science of São Tomé {and} Príncipe
             and
             Johnson {and} Johnson Fund for Scientific Research}
```

Biber allows you to use another string, other than the default `and` to separate lists and names (see [§3.7 List and Name Separators](https://mirrors.ctan.org/biblio/biber/documentation/biber.pdf#subsection.3.7)). To do that you can use the `--listsep` and `--namesep` command line options, like:

```
biber --listsep='und' <document>
```

then your list could be written:

```
publisher = {Foundation of Science of São Tomé and Príncipe
             und
             Johnson and Johnson Fund for Scientific Research}
```

However this change applies to the entire `.bib` file and since the separator cannot be changed in BibTeX, this makes your `.bib` file incompatible. But it's an option, either way.

---

Just for reference, moewe pointed out the section in the BibLaTeX manual ([§2.3.4 Literal Lists](https://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf#subsubsection.2.3.4) pp. 34–35 (v3.14)) that explains this:

> [image: The fields <code>institution</code>, <code>organization</code>, <code>publisher</code>, and location are literal lists in terms of §[2.2](https://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf#subsection.2.2). This also applies to <code>origlocation</code>, <code>origpublisher</code> and to the field aliases <code>address</code> and <code>school</code>. All of these fields may contain a list of items separated by the keyword ‘and’. If they contain a literal ‘<code>and</code>’, it must be wrapped in braces.<pre><code>publisher = {William Reid {and} Company},<br>institution = {Office of Information Management {and} Communications},<br>organization = {American Society for Photogrammetry {and} Remote Sensing<br> and<br> American Congress on Surveying {and} Mapping},</code></pre>Note the difference between a literal ‘<code>{and}</code>’ and the list separator ‘<code>and</code>’ in the above examples. You may also wrap the entire name in braces.]

and [BibTeX's manual](https://mirrors.ctan.org/biblio/bibtex/base/btxdoc.pdf) (`texdoc bibtex`) also hints at this feature:

> [image: This final item of the section describes BibTeX’s names (which appear in the <code>author</code> or <code>editor</code> field) in slightly more detail than what appears in Appendix B of the LaTeX book. In what follows, a “name” corresponds to a person. (Recall that you separate multiple names in a single field with the word “<code>and</code>”, surrounded by spaces, and not enclosed in braces. This item concerns itself with the structure of a single name.)]

(emphasis in “the word ‘`and`’, surrounded by spaces, and not enclosed in braces”).

Comment: I guess technically BibTeX doesn't have literal lists, but it's the same for name lists. In the interest of accessibility can I ask you to copy the relevant sections of the screenshots into the alt text of the images - or just post the quotes from the manuals directly as text instead of using images? (I can do it myself later, but I need to get some sleep now.)

Comment: @moewe You're probably right. I just added the reference to illustrate that writing `{and}` works for both. Sure! I added the alt text. Have a good night!

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: `biber` allows you change the list/name separator.

Comment: @PLK Cool, I didn't know that. I added to the answer. Thanks for pointing it out!